# Multiple div open and close on a click with div divided into left and right

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two `div`s (left and right). If a link is clicked in the left `div`, it should open data in the right `div` where there are multiple questions. Each question is clickable and displays answers on click.

I have implemented the following, but when a question opens the previous question stays open and doesn't close. I tried using `toggle` which closes the same link.

My JavaScript:

```
$('.targetDiv').hide();
$('.show').click(function () {
    $('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).toggle();
});
$('.innerdiv').hide();
$('.answer').click(function() {
    $('#innerdiv' + $(this).attr('target')).toggle();   
});
```

My HTML:

```
<div style="width: 30%; float:left">
    <div class="buttons">
        <ul>
            <li><a  class="show" target="1">Placing an Order</a></li>
            <li><a  class="show" target="2">blah.com Returns & Cancellations FAQs</a></li>
            <li><a  class="show" target="3">Brands & Stock</a></li>
            <li><a  class="show" target="4">Shipping & Delivery</a></li>
            <li><a  class="show" target="5">Payment</a></li>
            <li><a  class="show" target="6">Pricing</a></li>
            <li><a  class="show" target="7">Value Added Tax (VAT)</a></li>
            <li><a  class="show" target="8">Privacy & Security</a></li>
            <li><a  class="show" target="9">About the Company</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div style="width: 70%; float:right">
    <div id="div1" class="targetDiv">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="answer" target="1">I need personal assistance with my order. Who can I contact?</a><div id="innerdiv1" class="innerdiv" >Our customer service centre is happy to assist you with your order on +91 124 6733300 (10 AM - 7 PM)</div></li>
            <li><a class="answer" target="2" >How do I start a new account?</a><div id="innerdiv2" class="innerdiv">blah blah </div></li>
            <li><a class="answer" target="3">I am having problems ordering through your website. What can I do?</a> <div id="innerdiv3" class="innerdiv"> hahahahah </div></li>
            <li><a class="answer" target="4" >I need personal assistance with my order. Who can I contact?</a> <div id="innerdiv4" class="innerdiv"> b;la ablahhap </div></li>
            <li><a class="answer" target="5" >How do I start a new account?</a><div id="innerdiv5" class="innerdiv">blah blah </div></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>​
```

See JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/C59bE/8/

Comment: Be nice if you setup a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: It is working fine..check the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zg6Kf/    what is the problem?

Comment: I am sorry I edited the code again.In previous case toggle did not work I want toggle and hide both together.

Comment: I am sorry I just changed it. In the fiddle you shared @suresh ponnukalai toggle did not work.

Comment: Worked also for me but its working for Placing an Order

Comment: you have removed some code in your previous fiddle and saying your code is not working. why?

Comment: because toggle did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: **[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zg6Kf/5/)**

Maybe this is what you are looking for:

```
$(this).parent().siblings().find('div[id*=innerdiv]').hide();
```

This selects all the other #innerdivs* and hide it.

Like:

```
  $('.targetDiv').hide();
  $('.show').click(function () {
        $('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).toggle();
    });
  $('.innerdiv').hide();
  $('.answer').click(function(){
  $(this).parent().siblings().find('div').hide();
  $('#innerdiv' + $(this).attr('target')).toggle();   
  });
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zg6Kf/5/)**

Answer (score 1):

Why not just select all the innerdivs beforehand and hide them, before toggling the one that belongs to your target?
http://jsfiddle.net/C59bE/9/

So that becomes:

```
$('.targetDiv').hide();
    $('.show').click(function () {
       $('#div' + $(this).attr('target')).toggle();
    });
$('.innerdiv').hide();
$('.answer').click(function(){
    $('.innerdiv').hide();
 $('#innerdiv' + $(this).attr('target')).toggle();   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to hide all the innerdivs before displaying the one clicked on:

```
$('.answer').click(function(){
    $(".innerdiv").hide();
    $('#innerdiv' + $(this).attr('target')).toggle();  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanx I got the answer using this very easily.

```
 $('.answer').click(function(){
    var $target = $('#innerdiv' + $(this).attr('target')).toggle();   
    $('.targetDiv .innerdiv').not($target).hide()
});
```